# How to hide a textbox control when clicking on a linkbutton where these both are child controls to gridview?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a grid view as under

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgTask" runat="server" Width="100%" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="dgTask_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskID" HeaderText="TaskID" ItemStyle-Width="1%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskName" HeaderText="Task Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left"
                    ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PriorityName" HeaderText="Priority" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                    ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusName" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                    ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit Task" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEdit" runat="Server" Text="Edit" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' /> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Now, what I have to do is that on click event of the linkButton, i need to hide the text box controls for that row.

How to do so?

So far I have done as under

```
protected void dgTask_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton btnEdit = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("lnkBtnEdit");
            btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Test();");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, just make minor changes in calling the javascript function and also add the javascript function as below.

```
protected void dgTask_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton btnEdit = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("lnkBtnEdit");
            TextBox txtId = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("txtId");
            btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return Test("'" + txtId.ClientId + "'");");
        }
    }
```

And add Javascript like this way,

```
function Test(var txtId)
{
    var inputtxt = document.getElementById(txtId);
    if(inputtxt != null)
    {
        inputtxt.Attributes.Add("style","display:none;");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton b = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
        ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[r.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox1"))).Visible = false;
    }
```